# How set default collation in Oracle by default BINARY_CI for new Tables?

Tags: oracle, collation

I wrote script to change all tables default collation:

```
BEGIN
    FOR rc IN (
        SELECT * FROM ALL_ALL_TABLES WHERE owner='SchemaName' AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('__EFMigrationsHistory') 
    )
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rc.TABLE_NAME);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "SchemaName"."' ||  rc.TABLE_NAME || '" DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

After that I have removed varchar indexes, changed COLLATION of columns and created index again.

How I can set DEFAULT COLLATION for new tables by default?
Change User default collation doesn't work for it:

```
ALTER USER SchemaName DEFAULT COLLATION BINARY_CI;
```